# PHPExcel 1.7.8 PHPExcel_Writer_Excel5 Generate Corrupted xls

Tags: php, phpexcel

I have some code which reads in Excel files as templates and generate Excel output for users to download.  It used to work without any problem under PHP 5.4.7 + PHPExcel 1.7.7.  However, it started generating corrupted *.xls files after upgrading to PHPExcel 1.7.8.  So far, it seems the reader part is good but not the writer.  And it happens on some xls files while others remain fine.

Here is the snippet for demonstrating the problem:

```
<?php
require_once 'PHPExcel.php';

function testme()
{
    $sFile = 'test.output.xls';

    $objReader = new PHPExcel_Reader_Excel5();
    $obj = $objReader->load('test.tpl.xls');

    # corrupted
    $writer = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel5($obj);
    $writer->save($sFile);

    # normal
    $writer2 = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($obj);
    $writer2->save($sFile . 'x');
}

testme();
```

Has anybody experienced similar problem?

p.s. I wish I could attach the problematic Excel template file here.

Comment: Open the problematic file in a text editor, and look for leading or trailing white space (spaces, tabs, new lines, BOM markers) at the beginning and end of the file, and also for any obvious PHP error messages in the file

Comment: @MarkBaker Tried, but no BOM (UTF-16/UTF-8) found at the beginning / end of the file.  No PHP error message can be found neither.

Comment: Then it's going to take a lot more investigation of exactly what PHPExcel is generating to identify the cause of the problem, especially as it's the BIFF binary format that's the problem - can you upload a copy to the PHPExcel site on codeplex for investigation